# Cosets of submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Suppose we have a ring $R$ and an ideal $J \subseteq R$. Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $N$ be a submodule of $M$. Assume for two elements $m$ and $m'$ of $M$ we have 
$$m+ JM=m'+JM.$$

Since $N \subseteq M$ is a submodule, is it true that 
$$m + JN= m' +JN?$$

Comment: What if $N=0$? (There are plenty of counterexamples in this case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is wrong. For instance, take $R=\Bbb Z = J$, $M=2\Bbb Z$, $N=4\Bbb Z$.

Then:

> $2+JM=4+JM$, but $2+JN≠4+JN$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $J$ be the annihilator of $N$, but suppose $JM\ne\{0\}$ (in particular $N\ne\{0\}$). Suppose also that $JM\cap N\ne\{0\}$ and take $x\in JM\cap N$, $x\ne0$.

Then, of course, $x+JM=0+JM$, but $x+JN\ne 0+JN$.

Now the task is to find such a situation.

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $p$ a prime and set $M=\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$. Let $N=p\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$.

Then the annihilator of $N$ is $J=p\mathbb{Z}$ and $JM=N$.

So your conjecture can fail even if you assume $m,m'\in N$.